# How to find the database relationship between Project, activity, and sub-activity

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I am building a database for contracting company. I am facing a problem with the following situation:

For each project, there are many activities and similarly for each activity there are many sub-activities.

For example, Hospital building construction is the project. One of its activities is the emergency building construction. This activity has many sub-activities; one of them is electrical wiring. I decided to create the following tables:

Project and Activity. These two tables have the relation many-to-many. Therefore, I created a table called FollowUpSchedule which has Project ID and Activity ID.

My question is how to build the Sub-activity table and connect it to the activity? Should I create another table that has the activity ID and the sub-activity ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood it, i can think of two options:

**First solution**

Create another table to hold the sub reports, as you mentioned.

Activity Table

- ActivityID
- Activity Name

SubActivity Table

- ID
- ActivityID
- Name

**Second solution (I prefer it)**

Change the Activity table to support child parent structure.

If every sub activity is belongs to parent activity you can implement hierarchy structure

Your table structure should be something like this:

- ActivityID
- ParentID (0 - in case of root)
- Activity Name

And etc....